# node-openalpr in a raspberry pi 3 compiles but does not identify plate images

Tags: node.js, raspbian, openalpr

I'm working a project with openalpr and a raspberry pi 3 with node.js.

I already compiled OpenAlpr and works from the command line, now I'm trying to recognize a license plate from an image using node-openalpr module and find the next results:

Ran the program as root:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/nodeopenalpr $ sudo node index.js
Before Start.
Start:  true
Before getting version
version:  2.2.4
Before loop:  0
Before IdentifyLicense Execution
pi@raspberrypi:~/nodeopenalpr $
```

Ran the program as current user:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/nodeopenalpr $ node index.js
Before Start.
Start:  true
Before getting version
version:  2.2.4
Before loop:  0
Before IdentifyLicense Execution
working
exception in identify method:  ReferenceError: identifyResult is not defined
    at identify (/home/pi/nodeopenalpr/index.js:19:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/nodeopenalpr/index.js:36:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:456:3
After loop:  0
Before loop:  1
Before IdentifyLicense Execution
Segmentation fault
pi@raspberrypi:~/nodeopenalpr $
```

The version of the software I'm using is as follows:

- OpenAlpr (v2.2.4 Compiled in the hardest way)
- Node.js (v6.2.1)
- npm (v3.9.3)

This is the code I'm running:

```
        // statements
var openalpr = require ("node-openalpr");
//console.log("OPENALPR: ", openalpr);

function identify (id, path) {
    try {
        // statements
        console.log("Before IdentifyLicense Execution");
        console.log(openalpr.IdentifyLicense (path, function (error, output) {
            console.log("Finish IdentifyLicense. Output: ", output);
            console.log("Finish IdentifyLicense. Error: ", error);
            var results = output.results;
            console.log (id +" "+ output.processing_time_ms +" "+ ((results.length > 0) ? results[0].plate : "No results"));

            if (id == 349) {
                console.log (openalpr.Stop ());
            }
        }));
        console.log("After plate identification: ", openalpr);
    } catch(e) {
        // statements
        console.log("exception in identify method: ", e);
    }
}

try {
    console.log("Before Start.");
    console.log("Start: ", openalpr.Start ("/usr/local/share/openalpr/config/openalpr.defaults.conf", "/usr/local/share/openalpr/runtime_data", 4,true));

    console.log("Before getting version");
    console.log("version: ", openalpr.GetVersion ());

    for (var i = 0; i < 350; i++) {
        console.log("Before loop: ", i);
        identify (i, "/home/pi/nodeopenalpr/lp.jpg");
        console.log("After loop: ", i);
    }
} catch(e) {
    // statements
    console.log("Exception captured: ", e);
}
```

I'm trying to figured out this several time. I'll be very grateful for the help.

Héctor

Comment: Would be nice to have everything typed rather than having screenshots. That way the logs can be crawled by Google and others having your problem can end up here (maybe with a solution 'cause they solved it theirselves? who knows :D).

Comment: Thanks in advanced, i just changed